# Error while trying to overload << operator

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, operator-overloading

I can't get  the below code to compile while trying to overload the << operator. Can anyone point whats going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& i, int n)
{
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the error message issued by compiler.

Comment: Please when asking a question, provide the error message, I can see some very wrong stuff in your code, but the error message would have helped anyway.

Comment: You're not doing it wrong, this is the way to overload a stream operator. However the one for "int" already exists (hence the message : operator <<' is ambiguous). Try it again with a type (struct) of your own, say struct my_struct {int i=1;} and then overload for my_struct

Comment: As the error message from the compiler (which you saw fit to not provide) would have told you, there is already `operator<<()` that accepts an `std::ostream` and an `int`.     Since you have presented the compiler with two equally good operators (in terms of types of the operand) that match `std::cout << 5`,  the compiler cannot pick one over the other.   The wording of the compiler's error message is compiler-specific, but this is usually reported as "ambiguity"  i.e. it is ambiguous which operator to call.  Short solution:   remove your hand-rolled `operator<<()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already defined the operator << for an object of the type int in the C++ standard library

```
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(int n);
```

so this call of the operator in this statement

```
std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
```

is ambiguous because the standard operator is found due to the argument dependent lookup.

To disactivate the ADL you could write for example something like the following calling the operator explicitly with two arguments

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& i, int n)
{
    return i.operator <<( n );
}

int main()
{
    operator <<( std::cout, 5 ) << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5
```

Though it does not make a great sense.:)

Answer (score 1):

Because **more than one operator "<<" matches these operands.**

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& i, int n)` has been defined.

**Operator can be overload, not override.**

*operator* works like this:
`TypeA a = (TypeB)operand1 operator (TypeC)operand2`

see operator as a function, it translates to this func:
`TypeA operator(TypeB operand1, TypeC operand2)`

Define the func twice would cause compile error.

To overload **<<**, try:
`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& i, OtherType n)`
or
`AnyType operator<<(AnyType i, AnyType n)`

Just do not repeat.